# Como definir uma função que calcule a menor velocidade?

Tags: python, algoritmo, funções

O programa deve possuir uma função que calcule a menor velocidade dentre as que forem calculadas a partir dos dados fornecidos. O usuário deve fornecer como entrada, 9 valores, de 3 em 3, que correspondem a velocidade, aceleração e tempo decorrido para 3 carros diferentes. O programa deve calcular, a partir desses dados, a velocidade de cada carro, e imprimir a menor delas. Como estou tentando:

```
def velkmh(Vi, A, T):
    V = Vi + A * T
    return V
vi1 = float(raw_input())
a1 = float(raw_input())
t1 = float(raw_input())
velkmh(vi1, a1, t1)
V1 = velkmh(vi1, a1, t1) * 3.6
vi2 = float(raw_input())
a2 = float(raw_input())
t2 = float(raw_input())
velkmh(vi2, a2, t2)
V2 = velkmh(vi2, a2, t2) * 3.6
vi3 = float(raw_input())
a3 = float(raw_input())
t3 = float(raw_input())
velkmh(vi3, a3, t3)
V3 = velkmh(vi3, a3, t3) * 3.6
```

Comment: Sua função `velkmh` não deveria retornar alguma coisa? Além disso, o que é 3.6?

Comment: 3.6 é a constante para transformar m/s em km/h, esqueci de mencionar isso. Eu tentei aplicar a função para cada conjunto de valores dados, mas creio que fiz errado. Imaginei que os valores calculados seriam armazenados pelo programa para que pudessem ser usados depois.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Sugiro que troque `V = ....` por `return ....`. Além disso, se a velocidade em Km/h não é útil, faça sua função retornar a velocidade já em m/s (ou seja, mova o `* 3.6` para dentro da função). Acredito que isso vai ajudar.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações no código. Agora só preciso que o programa analise cada valor, escolha o menor e o imprima. Retornarei com a resposta, se achar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações. Ficou assim:

```
def velocidadeEmMetrosPorSegundo(Vi, A, T):
    V = Vi + A * T
    return V * 3.6

vi1 = float(raw_input())
a1 = float(raw_input())
t1 = float(raw_input())
V1 = velocidadeEmMetrosPorSegundo(vi1, a1, t1)

vi2 = float(raw_input())
a2 = float(raw_input())
t2 = float(raw_input())
V2 = velocidadeEmMetrosPorSegundo(vi2, a2, t2)

vi3 = float(raw_input())
a3 = float(raw_input())
t3 = float(raw_input())
V3 = velocidadeEmMetrosPorSegundo(vi3, a3, t3)

print("A menor velocidade é: " + min(V1, V2, V3))
```

Primeiro, fiz a função já retornar o valor multiplicado por `3.6`, já que o valor em Km/h não é útil para nada. Mudei o nome da função para ficar de acordo. Sugiro que deixe seus nomes bem descritivos, mesmo que isso os deixe longos. Você perde um pouco de tempo agora mas ganha no futuro.

Você está chamando a função duas vezes. Removi as chamadas que não capturam o retorno.

Separei em blocos lógicos para facilitar a leitura.

Por fim, usei a função `min`, que faz exatamente o que você precisa: seleciona o menor valor dentre os passados.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz da seguinte maneira e funcionou. Grato pela ajuda! Só agora vi sua resposta.

```
    def velkmh(Vi, A, T):
        V = Vi + A * T
        return V
    vi1 = float(raw_input())
    a1 = float(raw_input())
    t1 = float(raw_input())
    velkmh(vi1, a1, t1)
    V1 = velkmh(vi1, a1, t1) * 3.6
    vi2 = float(raw_input())
    a2 = float(raw_input())
    t2 = float(raw_input())
    velkmh(vi2, a2, t2)
    V2 = velkmh(vi2, a2, t2) * 3.6
    vi3 = float(raw_input())
    a3 = float(raw_input())
    t3 = float(raw_input())
    velkmh(vi3, a3, t3)
    V3 = velkmh(vi3, a3, t3) * 3.6
    lista = [V1, V2, V3]
    print min(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte script:

```
def velocidade_media(ve, ac, te):
    velocidades_kmh = list()
    for v, a, t in zip(ve, ac, te):
        velo = (v + (a * t))
        velocidades_kmh.append(velo)
    menor_kmh = min(velocidades_kmh)
    menor_ms = (menor_kmh * 3.6)
    return menor_kmh, menor_ms


n = int(input('Quantos veículos serão estudados? '))
vel = list()
ace = list()
tem = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    vel.append(float(input(f'Digite a velocidade inicial do {c}º carro: ')))
    ace.append(float(input(f'Digite a aceleração do {c}º carro: ')))
    tem.append(float(input(f'Digite o temp de percurso do {c}º carro, em horas: ')))

menor_velo_km, menor_velo_ms = velocidade_media(vel, ace, tem)

print(f'\033[32mA menor velocidade em "Km/h" é: {menor_velo_km:.2f} Km/h')
print(f'A menor velocidade em "m/s" é: {menor_velo_ms:.2f} m/s')
```

Observe que quando executamos este script, devemos informar a quantidade de veículos que participarão do estudo (análise). Em seguida, devemos inserir `velocidade inicial` (Km/h), `aceleração` (Km/h^2) e o `tempo` de percurso (h).

A partir desse momento os valores capturados serão armazenados nas listas `vel`, `ace` e `tem` que são respectivamente as listas de velocidades, acelerações e tempos.

Posteriormente estas listas são enviadas como parâmetros para a função `velocidade_media`. Chegando lá, estas listas serão simultaneamente, percorridas pelo laço de repetição `for` com ajuda da função `zip`, calculando para cada n-ésima interação o valor de sua  `velocidade final` em `Km/h` e, em seguida, armazenado os respectivos valores na lista `velocidades_kmh`. Posteriormente é calculada a menor velocidade em Km/h (menor_kmh) e, em seguida, tal velocidade é convertida para `m/s` (menor_ms).

Depois disso a função `velocidade_media` retornará dois valores, que são respectivamente, `menor_kmh` e `menor_ms`.

Logo em seguida as funções print exibirão os valores da menor velocidade em Km/h (menor_kmh) e menor velocidade em m/s (menor_ms).